# How do I do a screenshot on a RCA 10" tablet?

Tags: tablet, screenshots

My RCA only has touch screen volume control. Holding down the power while touching volume down doesn't work. Is there another way?

Comment: Some Android versions have a screenshot button in the shutdown menu that you get if you press power for about two seconds.

Comment: If your power menu doesn't offer screenshot button, you can try a myriad of apps which can add a screenshot tile in Quick settings. Use that tile to take screenshot. See https://play.google.com/store/search?q=screemshot tile quick settings&c=apps